# Why to design for mobile and scale to desktop with media query?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

In the [W3schools tutorial on CSS3 media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) they recommend to have the standard layout adapted to mobile viewing, and have a media query "scale it up" to desktop format when viewing on a desktop instead of the other way around. This should make the page display faster on mobile devices.

**What is the reasons that it will display faster?**

The obvious one would be that the mobile devices have less computing power and shouldn't have to do the media query and change the layout -- but can that really put some tension on the mobile's processor that is worth considering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real issue is that a mobile device has much less space for displaying than a desktop. While upscaling few information is easy, it's almost impossible to downscale large information in a tidy manner.

In other words, I would say the issue is not rendering speed, as much as a question of design practicalities.